# Kotlin use variable used in a while loop

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sockets, while-loop, bufferedreader

I want to use a function in loop condition and reuse it in the loop, like this code in Java, but I want it in kotlin :

```
while ( (data = in.readLine()) != null ) {
    System.out.println("\r\nMessage from " + clientAddress + ": " + data);
}
```

I tried copying this code in android studio to automatically convert to Kotlin and the code looks like this :

```
while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
    Log.d("Line", line)
    lines.add(line)
}
```

So I managed to get the lines with `var line = ""` before the loop, but the loop doesn't stop when the reader is done getting the message sent from the socket.

My wish is to send 2 messages through the socket, so I try to get all lines of one message, and when the second one arrives, I have to clear my lines variable to get the next message, but I can't.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reader.lineSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-buffered-reader/line-sequence.html) function:

```
reader.lineSequence().forEach {
    Log.d("Line", it)
    lines.add(it)
}
```

Or as suggested in documentation, you can improve it by using [File.useLines()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/use-lines.html) which automatically closes the File reader so you don't have to do it manually

Comment: You missed naming the lambda variable to `line`.

Comment: Ok so your code works to get the line, but doesn't stop when the reader is done getting the first message or even the second one, the foreach loop doesn't finish even if my server stops to send messages.